# Footer Formatting Problem - Placing Footer Directly Under Content

Tags: html, css, slider, footer, photo

I have a footer on this site that I'm building and have set it so that it appears just under the content of my website. When I have some paragraphs or photos linked on a page this footer appears just below the content (as I would like it to), but when I try to use photos in a slider, the footer doesn't appear under this slider, rather it overlaps the photos.

I would like to set the footer so that it appears just below the photo slider (not too far down the page) as it does on other pages. Any advice on how to format the footer properly would be much appreciated.

[Current Footer Position](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gFXsh.jpg)

[Desiered Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZAWG1.jpg)

Below is my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en; jp;">     
    
<body style="background-color: white;">
      
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">  
      
<div class="page-wrap">
     
<div class="cp_cont">
<input id="cp_toggle03" type="checkbox"/>
<div class="cp_mobilebar">
<label for="cp_toggle03" class="cp_menuicon">
<span></span>
</label>
</div>
<label id="h-menu_black" class="cp_toggle03" for="cp_menuicon"></label>
<div id="body" class="noscroll"></div>
        
<header class="cp_offcm03">
        
<nav>
<ul style="text-align: center; margin-left: 210px; overflow: hidden;">
            
<li style="border-bottom: .05px solid lightgray;"><a href="#">ホーム</a></li>
<li style="border-bottom: .05px solid lightgray;"><a href="#">ブログ</a></li>
<li style="border-bottom: .05px solid lightgray;"><a href="#">小泉ついて</a></li>
<li style="border-bottom: .05px solid lightgray;"><a href="#">参考文献</a></li>
    
            
<div class="searchbar"> 
            
<form id="frmSearch" class="search2" method="get" action="default.html" style=" padding-right: 20px; padding-top: 20px; text-align: right; position: inline;"/>
<input class="search2" id="txtSearch" type="text" name="serach_bar" size="31" maxlength="255" value="" style="center: 396px; top: 185px; width: 180px; height: 26px;"/>
<input class="search1" type="submit" name="submition" value="検索" style=" padding-  
bottom:20px; left: 0px; top: 153px; height: 25px; width: 32px;"/>
<input class="search2" type="hidden" name="sitesearch" value="default.html"/>    
    
    
<script type="text/javascript">
 document.getElementById('frmSearch').onsubmit = function() {
 window.location = 'http://www.google.com/search?q=site:yoursitename.com ' + document.getElementById('txtSearch').value;
        return false;
    }
    
 document.getElementById('cp_toggle03').onchange = function() {
 if (document.getElementById('cp_toggle03').checked) {
 document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";
  } else {
 document.body.style.overflow = "";
  }
}    
    
</script>
         
</div> 
</ul>    
</nav>
</header>     
               
<div class="setsumei">
    
 <br><h1 style="text-align: center; font-size: 40px;">◯◯◯◯</h1>
    <br><p style="text-align: justify; font-size: 16px;"></p>
    
 <p style="text-align: center; font-size: 13px;">著者：◯◯◯◯</p>
 <p style="text-align: center; font-size: 13px;">撮影日：◯◯◯◯年◯◯月◯◯日</p>

<br><ul class="slider_fade">
    <li><img src="photos/Home_Page/geiko.JPG" width="85%"></li>
    <li><a href="photos/Links/Kansai/Kansai_html_photos/Kyoto_html_photo/Kyoto/Blog/Kongoji/Kongoji_html_photo/Kongoji.html"><img src="photos/Home_Page/Kongoji_homepage.jpg" alt="Kongoji_homepage.jpg" width="85%"></a></li>
    <li><img src="photos/Home_Page/fuji.JPG" width="85%"></li>
</ul>
        
</div>
</div>
    
<br><br><footer class="site-footer" style="font-size: 12px;">小泉© 2020年 | <a href="#">English</a></footer>
      
</div>
      
<style>
    
 .searchbar{float: right;}
    
 .image{text-align: center;}
    
 .setsumei{margin-left: 20px;
              margin-right: 20px;}
    
 .footer{width: 100%; 
           height: 40px; 
           text-align: center;
           border-top: 1px solid black; 
           position: inherit;
           bottom: 0;
           padding: 10px;}
    
 .page-wrap {
  min-height: 100%;
  /* equal to footer height */
  margin-bottom: -40px; 
}

 .page-wrap:after {
  content: "";
  display: block; 
  }

 .site-footer, .page-wrap:after {
  /* .push must be the same height as footer */
  height: 40px; 
}

 .site-footer {
  text-align: center;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
}
      
 .slider_fade {
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}

 .slider_fade > li {
        position: absolute;
        list-style: none;
        visibility: hidden;
        animation: anime_slider_fade 25s 0s infinite;
    }
 .slider_fade > li:nth-of-type(2) {
        animation-delay: 6s;
    }
 .slider_fade > li:nth-of-type(3) {
        animation-delay: 15s;
    }

 @keyframes anime_slider_fade {
        0% {
            visibility: visible;
            opacity: 0;
        }
        15% {
            opacity: 1;
        }
        33.3% {
            opacity: 1;
        }
        48.3% {
            opacity: 0;
        }
        100% {
            opacity: 0;
        }
}  
    

 *, *:before, *:after {
    padding-left: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    
}    

 ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}

 a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}
    
 .cp_cont {
    height: auto;
}
    
/* menu */
 .cp_offcm03 {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 5000;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    padding-top: 0;
    -webkit-transition: transform 0.3s ease-in;
            transition: transform 0.3s ease-in;
    text-align: center;
    color: black;
    background-color: white;
}
 .cp_offcm03 nav,
 .cp_offcm03 ul {
    height: 100%;
}

 .cp_offcm03 li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: -6px;
}

 .cp_offcm03 a {
    display: block;    
    padding: 15px 45px;
    margin-bottom: -5px;
    -webkit-transition: background-color .3s ease-in;
            transition: background-color .3s ease-in;
}
    
 .cp_offcm03 a:hover {
    background-color: lightgray;
}

/* menu toggle */
 #cp_toggle03 {
    display: none;
}

 #cp_toggle03:checked ~ .cp_offcm03 {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
                    transform: translateX(0);
}

 #cp_toggle03:checked ~ .cp_container {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
                    transform: translateX(0);
}

 .cp_mobilebar {
    display: none;
    
}

/* content */
 .cp_container {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    padding: 35px auto;
    -webkit-transition: transform .3s ease-in;
            transition: transform .3s ease-in;
}   

 .cp_content {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 20px;
    height: 65vh;
    text-align: center;

}

@media (max-width: 1050px)and (min-width: 480px) {
/* menu */
 .cp_offcm03 {
        position: fixed;
        left: -250px;
        overflow-y: hidden;
        width: 250px;
        height: 100%;
        padding-top: 40px;
        color: black;
        background-color: white;
        z-index: 1000;
    }
    
    
 .cp_offcm03 nav {
        background: white;
        border-right: 0.5px solid lightgray;
        margin-left: -210px;
    }
    
    
    
 .cp_offcm03 li {
        display: block;
        margin-right: 0;}

        
        
 .cp_offcm03 a {
        padding: 20px;
        
    }
    
/* menu toggle */
 .cp_mobilebar {
        display: block;
        z-index: 2000;
        position: relative;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        padding: 0 25px;
        width: 100%;
        height: 40px;
        background-color: white;
        border-bottom: .05px solid lightgray;
        
        
    }
    
 .cp_menuicon {
        display: block;
        position: relative;
        width: 25px;
        height: 100%;
        cursor: pointer;
        -webkit-transition: transform .3s ease-in;
                transition: transform .3s ease-in;
    }
 .cp_menuicon > span {
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        top: 55%;
        margin-top: -0.3em;
        width: 100%;
        height: 0.2em;
        border-radius: 1px;
        background-color: black;
        -webkit-transition: transform .3s ease;
                transition: transform .3s ease;
    }
 .cp_menuicon > span:before,
 .cp_menuicon > span:after {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        border-radius: 1px;
        background-color: black;
        -webkit-transition: transform .3s ease-in;
                transition: transform .3s ease-in;
    }
    
 .cp_menuicon > span:before {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(-0.6em);
                transform: translateY(-0.6em);
    }
 
 .cp_menuicon > span:after {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0.6em);
                transform: translateY(0.6em);
    }

 #cp_toggle03:checked + .cp_mobilebar .cp_menuicon { 
        -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
                transform: rotate(45deg);
    }
    
 #cp_toggle03:checked + .cp_mobilebar span:before,
 #cp_toggle03:checked + .cp_mobilebar span:after {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
                transform: rotate(90deg);
    }
    
 #cp_toggle03:checked ~ .cp_offcm03 {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
                transform: translateX(100%);
    }
    
 #cp_toggle03:checked ~ .cp_container {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(250px);
                transform: translateX(250px);
    }
    
 input:checked ~ #h-menu_black {
    display: block;/*カバーを表示*/
    opacity: .6;
}
    
 #h-menu_black {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 999;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: black;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: .7s ease-in-out;
}
    
/* content */
 .cp_container {
        top: 60px;
        height: 92vh;
        text-align: center; 
    } 
    
 .noscroll{
        overflow: hidden;
        position: fixed;
    }
    
</style> 
      
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you attach a screenshot of the issue

Comment: you want footer to be at bottom, right??

Comment: I've added a photo. You can view it via the link.

Yes, I'd like the footer to automatically come just under the content on the page.

Comment: I updated my answer it's like you want pls take a look and let me know @Richard

Answer (score 0):

I added a few photos from my side to test what was the problem I figured it out and fixed the footer. Now, it is fixed to bottom of the page. Here, take a look

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en; jp;">
  <body style="background-color: white">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

    <div class="page-wrap">
      <div class="cp_cont">
        <input id="cp_toggle03" type="checkbox" />
        <div class="cp_mobilebar">
          <label for="cp_toggle03" class="cp_menuicon">
            <span></span>
          </label>
        </div>
        <label id="h-menu_black" class="cp_toggle03" for="cp_menuicon"></label>
        <div id="body" class="noscroll"></div>

        <header class="cp_offcm03">
          <nav>
            <ul
              style="text-align: center; margin-left: 210px; overflow: hidden"
            >
              <li style="border-bottom: 0.05px solid lightgray">
                <a href="#">ホーム</a>
              </li>
              <li style="border-bottom: 0.05px solid lightgray">
                <a href="#">ブログ</a>
              </li>
              <li style="border-bottom: 0.05px solid lightgray">
                <a href="#">小泉ついて</a>
              </li>
              <li style="border-bottom: 0.05px solid lightgray">
                <a href="#">参考文献</a>
              </li>

              <div class="searchbar">
                <form
                  id="frmSearch"
                  class="search2"
                  method="get"
                  action="default.html"
                  style="
                    padding-right: 20px;
                    padding-top: 20px;
                    text-align: right;
                    position: inline;
                  "
                />
                <input
                  class="search2"
                  id="txtSearch"
                  type="text"
                  name="serach_bar"
                  size="31"
                  maxlength="255"
                  value=""
                  style="center: 396px; top: 185px; width: 180px; height: 26px"
                />
                <input
                  class="search1"
                  type="submit"
                  name="submition"
                  value="検索"
                  style="
                    padding-bottom: 20px;
                    left: 0px;
                    top: 153px;
                    height: 25px;
                    width: 32px;
                  "
                />
                <input
                  class="search2"
                  type="hidden"
                  name="sitesearch"
                  value="default.html"
                />

                <script type="text/javascript">
                  document.getElementById("frmSearch").onsubmit = function () {
                    window.location =
                      "http://www.google.com/search?q=site:yoursitename.com " +
                      document.getElementById("txtSearch").value;
                    return false;
                  };

                  document.getElementById("cp_toggle03").onchange =
                    function () {
                      if (document.getElementById("cp_toggle03").checked) {
                        document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";
                      } else {
                        document.body.style.overflow = "";
                      }
                    };
                </script>
              </div>
            </ul>
          </nav>
        </header>

        <div class="setsumei">
          <br />
          <h1 style="text-align: center; font-size: 40px">◯◯◯◯</h1>
          <br />
          <p style="text-align: justify; font-size: 16px"></p>

          <p style="text-align: center; font-size: 13px">著者：◯◯◯◯</p>
          <p style="text-align: center; font-size: 13px">
            撮影日：◯◯◯◯年◯◯月◯◯日
          </p>

          <br />
          <ul class="slider_fade">
    <li><img src="photos/Home_Page/geiko.JPG" width="85%"></li>
    <li><a href="photos/Links/Kansai/Kansai_html_photos/Kyoto_html_photo/Kyoto/Blog/Kongoji/Kongoji_html_photo/Kongoji.html"><img src="photos/Home_Page/Kongoji_homepage.jpg" alt="Kongoji_homepage.jpg" width="85%"></a></li>
    <li><img src="photos/Home_Page/fuji.JPG" width="85%"></li>
</ul>
        </div>
      </div>

      <br /><br />
      <footer class="site-footer" style="font-size: 12px">
        小泉© 2020年 | <a href="#">English</a>
      </footer>
    </div>

    <style>
      .searchbar {
        float: right;
      }

      .image {
        text-align: center;
      }

      .setsumei {
        margin-left: 20px;
        margin-right: 20px;
      }

      .footer {
        width: 100%;
        height: 40px;
        text-align: center;
        border-top: 1px solid black;
        position: inherit;
        bottom: 0;
        padding: 10px;
      }

      .page-wrap {
        min-height: 100%;
        /* equal to footer height */
        margin-bottom: -40px;
      }

      .page-wrap:after {
        content: "";
        display: block;
      }

      .site-footer,
      .page-wrap:after {
        /* .push must be the same height as footer */
        height: 40px;
      }

      .site-footer {
        text-align: center;
        border-top: 1px solid black;
        padding: 10px;
        bottom: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        right: 0px;
        margin-bottom: 0px;
        position: fixed;
        width: 100%;
        height: 50px;
        margin-top: -50px;
        z-index: 10;
        background-color: white;
      }

      .slider_fade {
        text-align: center;
        position: relative;
        z-index: 1;
      }

      .slider_fade > li {
        position: absolute;
        list-style: none;
        visibility: hidden;
        animation: anime_slider_fade 25s 0s infinite;
      }
      .slider_fade > li:nth-of-type(2) {
        animation-delay: 6s;
      }
      .slider_fade > li:nth-of-type(3) {
        animation-delay: 15s;
      }

      @keyframes anime_slider_fade {
        0% {
          visibility: visible;
          opacity: 0;
        }
        15% {
          opacity: 1;
        }
        33.3% {
          opacity: 1;
        }
        48.3% {
          opacity: 0;
        }
        100% {
          opacity: 0;
        }
      }

      *,
      *:before,
      *:after {
        padding-left: 0;
        margin: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
      }

      ol,
      ul {
        list-style: none;
      }

      a {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: black;
      }

      .cp_cont {
        height: auto;
      }

      /* menu */
      .cp_offcm03 {
        position: relative;
        z-index: 5000;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        overflow: auto;
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        padding-top: 0;
        -webkit-transition: transform 0.3s ease-in;
        transition: transform 0.3s ease-in;
        text-align: center;
        color: black;
        background-color: white;
      }
      .cp_offcm03 nav,
      .cp_offcm03 ul {
        height: 100%;
      }

      .cp_offcm03 li {
        display: inline-block;
        margin-right: -6px;
      }

      .cp_offcm03 a {
        display: block;
        padding: 15px 45px;
        margin-bottom: -5px;
        -webkit-transition: background-color 0.3s ease-in;
        transition: background-color 0.3s ease-in;
      }

      .cp_offcm03 a:hover {
        background-color: lightgray;
      }

      /* menu toggle */
      #cp_toggle03 {
        display: none;
      }

      #cp_toggle03:checked ~ .cp_offcm03 {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
        transform: translateX(0);
      }

      #cp_toggle03:checked ~ .cp_container {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
        transform: translateX(0);
      }

      .cp_mobilebar {
        display: none;
      }

      /* content */
      .cp_container {
        position: relative;
        top: 0;
        padding: 35px auto;
        -webkit-transition: transform 0.3s ease-in;
        transition: transform 0.3s ease-in;
      }

      .cp_content {
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding: 20px;
        height: 65vh;
        text-align: center;
      }
      img {
        height: 80vh;
        width: 100%;
        object-fit: scale-down;
        margin-bottom: 100px;
      }

      @media (max-width: 1050px) and (min-width: 480px) {
        /* menu */
        .cp_offcm03 {
          position: fixed;
          left: -250px;
          overflow-y: hidden;
          width: 250px;
          height: 100%;
          padding-top: 40px;
          color: black;
          background-color: white;
          z-index: 1000;
        }

        .cp_offcm03 nav {
          background: white;
          border-right: 0.5px solid lightgray;
          margin-left: -210px;
        }

        .cp_offcm03 li {
          display: block;
          margin-right: 0;
        }

        .cp_offcm03 a {
          padding: 20px;
        }

        /* menu toggle */
        .cp_mobilebar {
          display: block;
          z-index: 2000;
          position: relative;
          top: 0;
          left: 0;
          padding: 0 25px;
          width: 100%;
          height: 40px;
          background-color: white;
          border-bottom: 0.05px solid lightgray;
        }

        .cp_menuicon {
          display: block;
          position: relative;
          width: 25px;
          height: 100%;
          cursor: pointer;
          -webkit-transition: transform 0.3s ease-in;
          transition: transform 0.3s ease-in;
        }
        .cp_menuicon > span {
          display: block;
          position: absolute;
          top: 55%;
          margin-top: -0.3em;
          width: 100%;
          height: 0.2em;
          border-radius: 1px;
          background-color: black;
          -webkit-transition: transform 0.3s ease;
          transition: transform 0.3s ease;
        }
        .cp_menuicon > span:before,
        .cp_menuicon > span:after {
          content: "";
          position: absolute;
          width: 100%;
          height: 100%;
          border-radius: 1px;
          background-color: black;
          -webkit-transition: transform 0.3s ease-in;
          transition: transform 0.3s ease-in;
        }

        .cp_menuicon > span:before {
          -webkit-transform: translateY(-0.6em);
          transform: translateY(-0.6em);
        }

        .cp_menuicon > span:after {
          -webkit-transform: translateY(0.6em);
          transform: translateY(0.6em);
        }

        #cp_toggle03:checked + .cp_mobilebar .cp_menuicon {
          -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
          transform: rotate(45deg);
        }

        #cp_toggle03:checked + .cp_mobilebar span:before,
        #cp_toggle03:checked + .cp_mobilebar span:after {
          -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
          transform: rotate(90deg);
        }

        #cp_toggle03:checked ~ .cp_offcm03 {
          -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
          transform: translateX(100%);
        }

        #cp_toggle03:checked ~ .cp_container {
          -webkit-transform: translateX(250px);
          transform: translateX(250px);
        }

        input:checked ~ #h-menu_black {
          display: block; /*カバーを表示*/
          opacity: 0.6;
        }

        #h-menu_black {
          display: none;
          position: fixed;
          z-index: 999;
          top: 0;
          left: 0;
          width: 100%;
          height: 100%;
          background: black;
          opacity: 0;
          transition: 0.7s ease-in-out;
        }

        /* content */
        .cp_container {
          top: 60px;
          height: 92vh;
          text-align: center;
        }

        .noscroll {
          overflow: hidden;
          position: fixed;
        }
      }
    </style>
  </body>
</html>
```

[image: Updated CSS Screenshot]

Comment: The footer is at the bottom of the page, but the photo slider is covering the footer. Is there a way I can set the footer so that it comes below the photo slider and not underneath it? Also, I'd like the footer to be at the bottom of the page, but no move with it.

Comment: I edited  my answer. I added photos from my pc, also I attached a screen shot of what it looks like, isn't this what you want?? Also I added a z index so that footer won't get covered by images

Comment: I've added another photo to show what type of format I'm looking to achieve. I've achieved this on other pages I'm building, but for whatever reason doesn't work with the photo slider I'd like to use.

Answer (score 0):

```html
     <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en; jp;">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    
    <head>
        <style>
         footer {
            text-align: center;
            border-top: 1px solid black;
            padding: 10px;
            bottom: 0px;
            left: 0px;
            right: 0px;
            margin-bottom: 0px;
            position: fixed;
            width: 100%;
            height: 50px;
            margin-top: -50px;
            z-index: 10;
            background-color: white;
            }
            .center {
             display: block;
             margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
            width: 50%;
            }
            .searchbar{float: right;}
            .image{text-align: center;}
            .setsumei{margin-left: 20px;
                margin-right: 20px;}
            .page-wrap {
                min-height: 100%;
                /* equal to footer height */
                margin-bottom: -40px;
            }
            .page-wrap:after {
                content: "";
                display: block;
            }
        
            .slider_fade {
                text-align: center;
                position: relative;
                z-index: 1;
            }
            .slider_fade > li {
                position: absolute;
                list-style: none;
                visibility: hidden;
                animation: anime_slider_fade 25s 0s infinite;
            }
            .slider_fade > li:nth-of-type(2) {
                animation-delay: 6s;
            }
            .slider_fade > li:nth-of-type(3) {
                animation-delay: 15s;
            }
            @keyframes anime_slider_fade {
                0% {
                    visibility: visible;
                    opacity: 0;
                }
                15% {
                    opacity: 1;
                }
                33.3% {
                    opacity: 1;
                }
                48.3% {
                    opacity: 0;
                }
                100% {
                    opacity: 0;
                }
            }
            *, *:before, *:after {
                padding-left: 0;
                margin: 0;
                box-sizing: border-box;
            }
            ol, ul {
                list-style: none;
            }
            a {
                text-decoration: none;
                color: black;
            }
            .cp_cont {
                height: auto;
            }
            /* menu */
            .cp_offcm03 {
                position: relative;
                z-index: 5000;
                top: 0;
                left: 0;
                right: 0;
                bottom: 0;
                width: 100%;
                height: auto;
                padding-top: 0;
                -webkit-transition: transform 0.3s ease-in;
                transition: transform 0.3s ease-in;
                text-align: center;
                color: black;
                background-color: white;
            }
            .cp_offcm03 nav,
            .cp_offcm03 ul {
                height: 100%;
            }
            .cp_offcm03 li {
                display: inline-block;
                margin-right: -6px;
            }
            .cp_offcm03 a {
                display: block;
                padding: 15px 45px;
                margin-bottom: -5px;
                -webkit-transition: background-color .3s ease-in;
                transition: background-color .3s ease-in;
            }
            .cp_offcm03 a:hover {
                background-color: lightgray;
            }
    
            /* menu toggle */
            #cp_toggle03 {
                display: none;
            }
            #cp_toggle03:checked ~ .cp_offcm03 {
                -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
                transform: translateX(0);
            }
            #cp_toggle03:checked ~ .cp_container {
                -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
                transform: translateX(0);
            }
            .cp_mobilebar {
                display: none;
            }
            /* content */
            .cp_container {
                position: relative;
                top: 0;
                padding: 35px auto;
                -webkit-transition: transform .3s ease-in;
                transition: transform .3s ease-in;
            }
            .cp_content {
                margin: 0 auto;
                padding: 20px;
                height: 65vh;
                text-align: center;
            }
            @media (max-width: 1050px)and (min-width: 480px) {
                /* menu */
                .cp_offcm03 {
                    position: relative;
                    left: -250px;
                    overflow-y: hidden;
                    width: 250px;
                    height: 100%;
                    padding-top: 40px;
                    color: black;
                    background-color: white;
                    z-index: 1000;
                }
                .cp_offcm03 nav {
                    background: white;
                    border-right: 0.5px solid lightgray;
                    margin-left: -210px;
                }
                .cp_offcm03 li {
                    display: block;
                    margin-right: 0;}
                .cp_offcm03 a {
                    padding: 20px;
                }
                /* menu toggle */
                .cp_mobilebar {
                    display: block;
                    z-index: 2000;
                    position: relative;
                    top: 0;
                    left: 0;
                    padding: 0 25px;
                    width: 100%;
                    height: 40px;
                    background-color: white;
                    border-bottom: .05px solid lightgray;
                }
                .cp_menuicon {
                    display: block;
                    position: relative;
                    width: 25px;
                    height: 100%;
                    cursor: pointer;
                    -webkit-transition: transform .3s ease-in;
                    transition: transform .3s ease-in;
                }
                .cp_menuicon > span {
                    display: block;
                    position: absolute;
                    top: 55%;
                    margin-top: -0.3em;
                    width: 100%;
                    height: 0.2em;
                    border-radius: 1px;
                    background-color: black;
                    -webkit-transition: transform .3s ease;
                    transition: transform .3s ease;
                }
                .cp_menuicon > span:before,
                .cp_menuicon > span:after {
                    content: "";
                    position: absolute;
                    width: 100%;
                    height: 100%;
                    border-radius: 1px;
                    background-color: black;
                    -webkit-transition: transform .3s ease-in;
                    transition: transform .3s ease-in;
                }
    
                .cp_menuicon > span:before {
                    -webkit-transform: translateY(-0.6em);
                    transform: translateY(-0.6em);
                }
    
                .cp_menuicon > span:after {
                    -webkit-transform: translateY(0.6em);
                    transform: translateY(0.6em);
                }
    
                #cp_toggle03:checked + .cp_mobilebar .cp_menuicon {
                    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
                    transform: rotate(45deg);
                }
    
                #cp_toggle03:checked + .cp_mobilebar span:before,
                #cp_toggle03:checked + .cp_mobilebar span:after {
                    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
                    transform: rotate(90deg);
                }
    
                #cp_toggle03:checked ~ .cp_offcm03 {
                    -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
                    transform: translateX(100%);
                }
    
                #cp_toggle03:checked ~ .cp_container {
                    -webkit-transform: translateX(250px);
                    transform: translateX(250px);
                }
    
                input:checked ~ #h-menu_black {
                    display: block;/*カバーを表示*/
                    opacity: .6;
                }
    
                #h-menu_black {
                    display: none;
                    position: fixed;
                    z-index: 999;
                    top: 0;
                    left: 0;
                    width: 100%;
                    height: 100%;
                    background: black;
                    opacity: 0;
                    transition: .7s ease-in-out;
                }
    
                /* content */
                .cp_container {
                    top: 60px;
                    height: 92vh;
                    text-align: center;
                }
    
                .noscroll{
                    overflow: hidden;
                    position: rel;
                }
              
    
        </style>
    </head>
        <body>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6" s>
                    <div style="background-color: white;">
                    <div class="page-wrap">
                        <div class="cp_cont">
                            <input id="cp_toggle03" type="checkbox"/>
                            <div class="cp_mobilebar">
                                <label for="cp_toggle03" class="cp_menuicon">
                                    <span></span>
                                </label>
                            </div>
                            <label id="h-menu_black" class="cp_toggle03" for="cp_menuicon"></label>
                            <div id="body" class="noscroll"></div>
                            <header class="cp_offcm03">
                           
                                <nav>
                                    <ul style="text-align: center;">
                                        <li style="border-bottom: .05px solid lightgray;"><a href="#">ホーム</a></li>
                                        <li style="border-bottom: .05px solid lightgray;"><a href="#">ブログ</a></li>
                                        <li style="border-bottom: .05px solid lightgray;"><a href="#">小泉ついて</a></li>
                                         <li style="border-bottom: .05px solid lightgray;"><a href="#">参考文献</a></li>
                                        
                                        <div class="searchbar">
                                            <form id="frmSearch" class="search2" method="get" action="default.html" style=" padding-right: 20px; padding-top: 20px; text-align: right; position: inline;"/>
                                            <input class="search2" id="txtSearch" type="text" name="serach_bar" size="31" maxlength="255" value="" style="center: 396px; top: 185px; width: 180px; height: 26px;"/>
                                            <input class="search1" type="submit" name="submition" value="検索" style=" padding-  
    bottom:20px; left: 0px; top: 153px; height: 25px; width: 32px;"/>
                                            <input class="search2" type="hidden" name="sitesearch" value="default.html"/>
                                        </div>
                                    </ul>
                                </nav>
    
                            </header>
    
                            <div class="setsumei">
    
                                <br><h1 style="text-align: center; font-size: 40px;">◯◯◯◯</h1>
                                <br><p style="text-align: justify; font-size: 16px;"></p>
    
                                <p style="text-align: center; font-size: 13px;">著者：◯◯◯◯</p>
                                <p style="text-align: center; font-size: 13px;">撮影日：◯◯◯◯年◯◯月◯◯日</p>
    
                                <br>
                                <div class="center">
                                <ul class="slider_fade">
                                   
                                    <li><a><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_mountains.jpg" alt="Kongoji_homepage.jpg" width="85%"></a></li>
                                    <li><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_forest.jpg"  width="85%"></li>
                                    <li><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/img_forest.jpg"  width="85%"></li>
        
                                    <li><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_mountains.jpg"  width="85%"></li>
                                </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
                </div> 
            </div>
        </div>
    <footer style="font-size: 12px;">
        <p>小泉© 2020年 |</p><a href="#">English</a>
    </footer>
    
    </body>
    
    
    </html>
    
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementById('frmSearch').onsubmit = function() {
            window.location = 'http://www.google.com/search?q=site:yoursitename.com ' + document.getElementById('txtSearch').value;
            return false;
        }
    
        document.getElementById('cp_toggle03').onchange = function() {
            if (document.getElementById('cp_toggle03').checked) {
                document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";
            } else {
                document.body.style.overflow = "";
            }
        }
    
    </script>
```

Comment: This is the exact problem I've been having. It works perfectly when I don't use this photo slider, it works when I use non-moving photos. Maybe I should try using a different photo slider?

Comment: Please add your photo's and see if this will work for you

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work properly. The footer is overlapping the photo slider and for whatever reason, the photo slider appears at the bottom left of the screen, not in the center as I had set it.

Comment: @Richard The code is correct the footer is sticky so please scroll down to end of page as footer will stick to bottom of screen or open to full screen. Code form update to correct style . Image fade updated to align center